# How to build conditional list of dropdown options in Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel, conditional-statements, dropdown, html-select, voyager

I have a problem with Laravel Voyager v1.2. I need to filter list of related list of options in select dropdown easily by where condition. So let's say I have Post with relation to Category, but I don't want to list all Categories in select dropdown, but just that active ones.

1. I tried to force Voyager to take my own method to build an relationship in Post model:

```
public function category_id() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Post::class')->where('active',1);
}
```

2. Also tried to define scope in BREAD JSON options for the category field:

```
{
    "relationship": {
        "key": "id",
        "label": "name",
        "scopes": [
            "active"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Post Model part:**

```
public function scopeActive($query) {
  return $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

This is how my Post class look like (I don't actualy need to filter active categories, but food categories by it's IDs):

```
public function soup1() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Meal')->where('meal_category_id',1);
}


public function soup2() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Meal')->where('meal_category_id',1);
}

public function mealy() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Meal')->where('meal_category_id',7);
}

public function scopeSoups($query)
{
  return $query->where('meal_category_id', 1);
}

public function scopeMealy($query)
{
  return $query->where('meal_category_id', 7);
}
```

I want to receive filtered list of options instead of all model rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by overriding the blades in voyager:

### Step 1 :

Copy `relationship.blade.php`

**from:** `/"YourProject"/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/formfields/relationship.blade.php`

**To:** `/"YourProject"/resources/views/vendor/voyager/formfields/relationship.blade.php`

This way voyager will use this file in your your project views instead of the package file in the vendor.

Read More: [Voyager Documentations](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files#overriding-bread-views)

### Step 2 :

In the line 25 of `relationship.blade.php` you'll see this block of code:

```
            <select
                class="form-control select2-ajax" name="{{ $options->column }}"
                data-get-items-route="{{route('voyager.' . $dataType->slug.'.relation')}}"
                data-get-items-field="{{$row->field}}"
            >
                @php
                    $model = app($options->model);
                    $query = $model::where($options->key, $dataTypeContent->{$options->column})->get();
                @endphp

                @if(!$row->required)
                    <option value="">{{__('voyager::generic.none')}}</option>
                @endif

                @foreach($query as $relationshipData)
                    <option value="{{ $relationshipData->{$options->key} }}" @if($dataTypeContent->{$options->column} == $relationshipData->{$options->key}){{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>{{ $relationshipData->{$options->label} }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

Which you should override it with this:

```
            @if($options->table == 'categories')

                <div class="ap-form-input">
                    @php
                        $model = app($options->model);
                        $query = $model::where('active', true)->get();
                    @endphp

                    <select class="form-control select2" id="language-select" name="{{ $options->column }}">


                        @if(!$row->required)
                            <option value="">{{__('voyager::generic.none')}}</option>
                        @endif

                            @foreach($query as $relationshipData)
                                <option value={{ $relationshipData->{$options->key} }} @if($dataTypeContent->{$options->column} == $relationshipData->{$options->key}){{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>{{ $relationshipData->{$options->label} }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

            @else
                <div class="ap-form-input">
                    <select class="form-control select2" name="{{ $options->column }}">
                        @php
                            $model = app($options->model);
                            $query = $model::all();
                        @endphp

                        @if(!$row->required)
                            <option value="">{{__('voyager::generic.none')}}</option>
                        @endif

                        @foreach($query as $relationshipData)
                            <option value={{ $relationshipData->{$options->key} }} @if($dataTypeContent->{$options->column} == $relationshipData->{$options->key}){{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>{{ $relationshipData->{$options->label} }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            @endif
```

This way when you're using categories relationship you will only get the active categories.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your time and I completely understand your soulution. But this is the possible way just in the case of static value (active = true). Do you have some sugestion how to filter rows by a dynamic value (defined in Model or Controller)? As I mentioned i need to filter dropdown options by category ID, so there is no just one static value (true or false) but I would need an option to define the column and value to be filtered (for example give me all post where category_id = 1, another dropdown in the same bread right below this would be category_id = 2 etc.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BorisTetřev You're welcome, I don't think there is any dynamic solution available, but you can make this one dynamic by defining an array in the model with key and values that you want to filter, and use it in relationship.blade.php or anywhere else.

Comment: I just found out here is select2-ajax CSS class on every relationship selectbox, so i guess it checks if there is any result comming from query and If not, it calls some model from where it gets all rows in a table. Do you know if this works by this way? Thx a lot.

Comment: I'm not totally getting what you are looking for, explain more.

Comment: It's already done. I did it by overriding relationship blade as you adviced.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link and follow these simple steps, just now I solved my issue.

https://voyager.readme.io/docs/relationships